# Manipulating SVG, need to change color

Tags: javascript, svg, colors

I've got a little problem with a changing color module. 
It works a little. I'm gonna try to explain you.

There's a picture in SVG, with three colors that the user normally could change. So I manipulate my SVG with some jQuery, and it works... but... when the user changes one of the three color, goes to another color and comes back on the first color he changed, that doesn't work anymore.

I don't really understand why, and this is why I'm here to see if anyone could help me.

You could see the page [here](http://simon-tr.com/testProduct/).

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: The problem is that you seleting path based on color, you can add id or class to those paths and using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if($(this).attr('fill')==exColor)` is the problem, because `attr()` doesn't use the current value. You should use `css()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Just keep in mind the following scenario:

1. `Fond` changed to #FFFFFF
2. `Fond carte` changed to #FFFFFF
3. Now imagine you want to change `Route`: The whole map would change color, since everything (except the water) is white.

So in conclusion: Use names/classes for the different types to always change the correct parts, like jcubic said in his comment.